# javascript: how to display html file in window.alert?

Tags: javascript, messagebox

I have html file with `href` `hyperlinks`. I wanna show my html files in message box. `windows.alert` or any message box in javascript. But, it doesn't show my html file. rather it simply shows `htmlfiles/hello.html`. Guide me, how to open html file in message box.

HTML CODE:

```
<span onclick="alert()">click me</span>
```

Comment: Awesome. Can you upload a screenshot of what you want to achieve, because I can't wait to see it

Comment: if you alert it won't open file. BTW it javascript cannot access your local file system

Comment: `alert` can display plain text content only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is not possible with the standard widget from browser. You have the choice to develop it without or with an existing javascript framework.

Comment: Do you know what a 'Javascript framework' is? If not, take a look at ExtJs, Jquery-Ui, etc.